# How can I use a for-each loop to beautify a destructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, foreach, syntax, delete-operator

In case the question is a bit vague, let's use the example class `Paper`.

Let's say I have a dynamically allocated array of pointers:

```
Paper** myFolder;
```

and later, somewhere, it gets filled up with *n* pointers:

```
myFolder = new Paper* [n];
//trimmed - make each pointer in myFolder point to something
```

When we're done with `myFolder`, we need to delete each `Paper` before deleting the `Paper**` itself:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    delete myfolder[i];
```

---

**My question:** That code isn't very "pretty" now that C++11 and up have for each loops. How can I delete a dynamically allocated array of pointers work with the "for-each" syntax? The following is apparently syntactically incorrect:

```
for(Paper* p: myFolder)
    delete p;
```

or even

```
for each (Paper* p in myFolder)
    delete p;
```

---

**Additional Info:** `myFolder` is not an array of arrays. It is an array of pointers. Why? Because the objective is to take advantage of polymorphism. `Paper` may be subclassed, hence `myFolder` is an array of pointers rather than an array of objects.

Also: of course `std::vector` is a better approach than using raw pointers. *The question is theoretical and regards only the new C++ syntax.* I'm not looking for advice on how to redo this code.

Comment: [Ever Used Smart Pointers?](https://techoverflow.net/blog/2012/09/17/c11-iterate-over-smart-pointers-using-foreach-loop/)

Comment: for(Paper* p: myFolder) is incorrect because the range for-loop requires the collection to provide begin() and end() iterators—and a raw pointer doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want polymorphism, you need to hold pointers to your objects.
You currently use a pointer to a dynamically allocated array

> Paper** myFolder;

There is no need to manually control the allocation of the array, you can easily use

```
std::vector<Paper*> myFolder;
```

When destructing the folders, beautifully:

```
for(auto paper : myFolder) 
    delete paper;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. +1 for brevity.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) with some pointer arithmetic.

```
std::for_each(myFolder, myFolder + n, [](Paper* p){ delete[] p; })
```

However in the spirit of using modern C++, I would discourage using manual memory manipulation at all and using something with [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)

```
std::vector<std::vector<Paper>>
```

Comment: I will have to say , that `std::foreach` code looks a lot more unreadable or should i say "uglier" , than the previous normal for loop the OP Presented.

Comment: As the OP requires polymorphism, he will require std::vector<Paper*> or even std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Paper>>

Answer (score 0):

Raw pointers should really be avoided.

Below is an example to use `std::vector` for your problem.

```
#include <vector>

class Paper {
};

class Folder {
    // A folder contains a vector of papers.
    std::vector<Paper> m_papers;

public:
    // Method to add a paper to the folder. Use Move semantics for performance.
    void AddPaper(Paper && aPaper) {
        m_papers.push_back(std::move(aPaper));
    }

    // A read-only getter.
    const std::vector<Paper> & Papers() const { return m_papers; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Folder> folders;  // All your folders.
    Folder aFolder;   // Create a folder.
    aFolder.AddPaper(Paper());  // Add paper to the folder.
    folders.push_back(aFolder);  // Add a folder.

    for (const auto & f : folders) {
        for (const auto & p : f.Papers()) {
            // Read each paper here.
        }
    }
}
```

When using `std::vector`, a ranged for loop can be used to access each element:

```
for (const auto & f : folders)
```